# First time of VPS configuration

Tags: node.js, vps

I'm trying to upload a page to a VPS for the first time.

I'm getting this error, also, I'm not sure if it was correctly configured.

I uploaded it to a free hosting and if worked, I only had to set up port 3000.
I uploaded it exactly the same page, but it doesn't open.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUHcg.png)

Comment: That's really too little information, but I guess that port 3000 isn't accessible from outside.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry.
This is the first time I try to upload a node.js site with ejs, and not sure how to do it, at least, if there's any config I should do on the entry point.